# Replace Parts in List with Parts from other List

Tags: list-manipulation

I have two lists given by:

```
t1 = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}};
t2 = {a, b, c};
```

and want to replace the second parts of `t1` with `t2` to get

```
{{1,a},(3,b},{5,c}}
```

I tried

```
t1 /. {u_, v_} -> {u, #} & /@ t2
```

But it does not work. Where is my mistake?

Comment: `t1[[All, 2]] = t2`

Comment: Yes, but what would be the correct form I tried to apply? I'd like to know for more complicated lists.

Comment: I suppose you could use `Module[{i = 0}, t1 /. {x_, _} :> {x, t2[[++i]]}]`, seems fragile though

Comment: add `( )`. `t1 /. ({u_, v_} -> {u, #} & /@ t2)`

Comment: Yes, thanks! I tried brackets, but always put them in the wrong place!

Comment: `MapThread[ReplacePart[#1, -1 -> #2] &, {t1, t2}]`

Comment: Very interesting!

Answer (score 7):

"Correct form" would depend on how the lists are "more complicated". ReplaceAll works best for patterns, but you don't need patterns. I'd probably start with something like this:

```
Transpose[{t1[[All, 1]], t2}]
```

Answer (score 2):

The answer by @lericr is optimal with regards to minimality and I like it a lot. Another way to go about it is the following:

```
t1 = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}};
t2 = {a, b, c};

ArrayReshape[Riffle[First /@ t1, t2], {3, 2}]
```

> `{{1, a}, {3, b}, {5, c}}`

More automated for longer stuff

```
ArrayReshape[Riffle[First /@ t1, t2], {Length@t2, 2}]
```

the final `2` is informing Mathematica that you want collections of doubles in the final list.

Comment: Wow! I have never used ArrayReshape! Good!

Comment: @user57467 glad you liked it :-)

Answer (score 1):

An alternative way

```
t1 = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}};
t2 = {a, b, c};
list = Flatten[MapThread[List, {t1, #}] &@t2];
Partition[Drop[list, {2, Length@list, 3}], 2]
```

Edit: thanks to @lericr for the relevant comment about timings.

I think it should be sufficient to say that all of the algorithms yield a result of the order $10^{-6}$ when using `RepeatedTiming`.

Finally, the proper way of doing the timing for the proposed solution here would be something like

```
RepeatedTiming[
 Partition[
   Drop[Flatten[MapThread[List, {t1, #}] &@t2], {2, 
     Length[Flatten[MapThread[List, {t1, #}] &@t2]], 3}], 2];]
```

such that nothing is pre-computed.

Finally, an estimate of the length/complexity of the more realistic lists would be good to be able to compare the approaches.

Comment: I don't think timings are relevant since we don't know what the "more complicated lists" look like. But since you posted timings, I'll comment. (1) I think it's not quite apples-to-apples since the third algorithm was allowed to pre-compute `list`. (2) On my machine, the Riffle & ArrayReshape algorithm was slightly faster than the Transpose one.

Comment: @lericr thanks for pointing this out. Firstly, I did not mean to offend anyone, and this was just a rough estimation for larger lists. I have upvoted your answer long ago. Now, that this is out of the way, and hopefully none of the users of the site got offended, let me think a bit about it as I see your point. Perhaps, I should remove the estimates. Thanks again for bringing this up :)

Comment: I certainly wasn't offended! I think timings would be interesting if we knew the actual context (what "complicated lists" look like).

Comment: @lericr thanks again for the comment. Glad that at his time and age we can be civilized behind our screens :-)